# How to troubleshoot application page hung issues in Internet Explorer 11 in Windows 7

Tags: struts2, internet-explorer-11

we have a Struts 2 application. It has a web page that works fine in all browsers except IE 11. The page hangs while loading and stops responding. How to troubleshoot the page hung issues in IE 11 ? Please give some tips.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a virtual machine to achieve so. Refer to [Microsoft virtual machines download page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) for more information. The only problem is that you will be able to test IE8 as the minimum version. There is a specific VM with Windows 7 and Internet Explorer, so if you can use a VM you will be able to test your app.

Other possible solution is to use [IETester](https://ietester.softonic.com/), it has some bugs, but you can even download a debug bar for it.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, we were able to resolve the hung issue in IE browser. We did the following :

1. In IE, we opened the F12 Developer Tools and went to the Debugger tab.
2. Clicked on the page that was getting hung.
3. In the Debugger tab, it showed the line number that was resulting in error. The error was something like "method not supported". The code was 
   document.form.submit="post".

   4. Made changes in code to solve the error. I modified  tag with property method="post" instead of "get".

This fixed the issue.